# SwiftUI - Saving images with CoreData

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently saving the images as Binary Data and I do run into performance issues if I fetch and display the images when my view appears, if I remove the images problem solved. Tried to using LazyStacks but to no luck. I've been searching online to some questions, however, there are not any a definitive answers.

My questions are as follows:

- I'm wondering what is the best way to save records with images with CoreData? I've seen something about external storage and also saw a comment on here from years ago saying the following:

> As for the images, never ever store them in Core Data as binary blobs.
> Always store them as normal files on disk and store their path in Core
> Data to access them later on.

- In theory, how many records can CoreData save? I'd imagine with each addition of a record the file size of the database or equivalent would increase.

Thank you!

Comment: As the quote you added says, it's not recommended not to save images in CoreData. CoreData itself can hold many many records.. but that's not the problem here. The issue is that it's very slow to convert an image from a binary data file inside CoreData into an image for your app. I would recommend (1) saving images to a file path and storing the path as a String in CoreData (for common images that will be seen every time a user loads your app), or (2) not saving images and downloading them & temporarily storing them in an NSCache (for non-common images like profile pictures).

Comment: @nicksarno Essentially, the user takes a photo of an item, adds details and then proceeds to save the entry. I think the latter would be the best approach?

Comment: If the image is coming from the device and you don't have an external server to save the image to, you will need to save it locally. So use #1 then.